# Sum to $100$ game

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In the sum to $100$ game between two players that can choose any number frm $1$ to $10$, it is given in the book 'Trimathalon' by Paul Sally. 
The rule is simple that each player can choose in any round, any number from $1$ to $10$ (irrespective of chosing that number earlier, or not); and the one with reaching the cumulative sum of both players' values to be $100$ wins.
 The book states that: if one player has chosen the numbers : $1,2,4,1,10,6,9,2,1,8$; then would win.
But, it is also known that for one player to win, he must have the following cumulative sum value for the other player, in reverse order as: 
$89, 78, 67, 56,45,34,23,12,1$.

I want to know why the numbers given in the book are correct, as then need the other player to make choices as :
round 1: Player 1: $1$, desired sum total for player 2: $\,\,\,1$, Player 2: $9$ 
round 1: Player 1: $2$, desired sum total for player 2: $12$, Player 2: $7$ 
round 3: Player 1: $4$, desired sum total for player 2: $23$, Player 2: $10$

So, is the author assuming the above sequence of inputs by the Player 2, if so why?

Comment: If you'd like help, you should explain the rules of the game; most people don't know this book.

Comment: @vadim123 Edited to have the rule.

Comment: @jiten I was reading this as vadim's comment came in, and it was not obvious. The wording in your opening didn't even suggest it was a turn-based game. It sounded like a player might choose $1,2,4,1,10,6,9,2,1,8$ all at once.

Comment: Perhaps you might want to post this on the **puzzling.SE**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you say the book states is the *solution* to a *sample game* (at the top of page 6, opposite to the solution on page 7), in which your opponent has responded to your moves by picking $9,7,10,1,5,2,9,10$, and $3$, in that order. So after your (winning) first choice of $1$, what you're doing is responding with $11-k$ to each of your opponent's moves.

Comment: @jiten, you are welcome. The take-home lesson here is to try to make sure you've included all the relevant information when you post a question. Hopefully you see now that in this case you didn't.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that if you choose a number first I can choose a number to make the two add up to $11$.  Since I want to make the sum $100$, if I make the sum $89$ I will win.  You choose $n$, I choose $11-n$ and the sum becomes $100$.  Since $100$ is a winning number, so is $89$.  If I want to reach $89$ it suffices to reach $78$ because I can make the next two moves total $11$ and so on.  If I get to start, I choose $1$ and then nine pairs summing to $11$ will make the sum be $100$.

Comment: But, the issue is why the Player 1 should win by those values given, i.e. $1,2,4,1,10,6,9,2,1,8$. If so, then there is assumed a particular value by the other player in the corresponding rounds, as: $9,7,10,...$.

Comment: Player 1 cannot win by any specific series of values.  His values have to react to what Player 2 does.  You need to recognize the rules of the game that each player chooses his number in turn and announces it to the other.

Comment: Agreed, but  why the author is so confident about a particular set of values chosen by player 1.